# NativeScript + ngrx store + remote devtools

Tags: angular, nativescript, ngrx, ngrx-store, redux-devtools

I'm building mobile app using *NativeScript* with *Angular 2* and *TypeScript*. My IDE is VS Code.

I decided to use *@ngrx/store* to keep state of the application. However there is a problem with debugging store state. I'd like to use *redux-devtools* and I've read that in my case I have to use [remote-redux-devtools](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/remote-redux-devtools). The problem is it's supposed to work with [redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) and I cannot find any guide how to set it up for [ngrx](https://github.com/ngrx/platform).

*ngrx* supports devtools itself but I didn't manage to make it work following [this instruction](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store-devtools/README.md).

Have any of you done such a setup before and can help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @dzwonu, You could try using ngrx-devtools-nativescript plugin - https://github.com/vakrilov/ngrx-devtools-nativescript , which provides a support for the ngrx in NativeScript. However, something that I would suggest is using application-settings module -   https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/application-settings in case you need to store some data on the device locally.

Comment: @NikolayTsonev ngrx-devtools-nativescript requires embedding UI control in your template and I want to avoid this. Redux store is not about storing data locally on the device but to keep consistent state of your app and share it between components.

Comment: while using application settings data, you also could save the needed state of the application. Also, ones you have saved it in the module, you could also access the needed value inside the different components. -https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/tree/master/app/application-settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible right now to connect to remote redux devtools with Nativescript. It's theoretically possible. react-native can do it. ngrx on the web can do it. There just isn't any project that can connect ngrx to remote dev tools as of today.

https://github.com/vakrilov/ngrx-devtools-nativescript can embed it in the app - but that's very burdensome and not what you requested.